# How to make React <FontAwesomeIcon/> color changed on button hover?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

I am pretty much new to React and cannot solve this issue. Basically, I want to change only the color of the "FontAwesomIcon" tag while hovering the button but not the color of the text inside the "span" tag. I am using react-bootstrap as well. Here is my code,

```
<div class="tab">
   <Link to="/dataset-upload">
      <button class="tablinks" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCloudUploadAlt} size="lg"/> 
            <span>Dataset Upload</span>
      </button>
  </Link>
</div>
```

here is the CSS for FontAwesomeIcon,

```
.tab button FontAwesomeIcon:hover{
    color: #86BC25;
}
```

If I replace FontAwesomeIcon with span in the CSS it works.

I would appreciate any suggestion or piece of advice.

Comment: what about css ?

Comment: Hope this example helps https://codesandbox.io/s/font-awesome-and-react-kpoty

Comment: @ManirajMurugan, thank you for your rapid answer, It works perfectly if I hover on the icon only but I need the same effect while hovering the whole div. :)

Comment: @tabrez, Here you go https://codesandbox.io/s/react-simple-contact-list-1xvkn Also added as an answer with the code provided by you.. Hope my solution helps you..

Comment: @tabrez I updated my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60972154/8583669) to make it work if you also just put your mouse over the button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using CSS you can achieve the result,

**HTML:** Add a `className` say like `upload-icon` to the parent div and `className` say like `font-upload` to the `FontAwesomeIcon`.

```
<div className="tab upload-icon">
 <Link to="/dataset-upload">
   <button className="tablinks" onClick={this.handleClick}>
   <FontAwesomeIcon
     icon={faCloudUploadAlt}
     size="lg"
     className="font-upload"
      />
    <span>Dataset Upload</span>
    </button>
  </Link>
</div>
```

**CSS:** Upon hovering over parent div `upload-icon`, change color of `font-upload` like,

```
.upload-icon:hover .font-upload {
  color: green;
}
```

> [**Working sandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-simple-contact-list-1xvkn)

**Note:** Please consider using `className` instead of `class`.. [Ref Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989454/class-vs-classname-in-react-16)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `className` property on a `FontAwesomeIcon` component.

So just write a css rule:

```css
.tablinks:hover .fa-icon {
  color: red;
}
```

and then give this class to the component:

```html
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCloudUploadAlt} size="lg" className="fa-icon" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Since CSS can do a lot, I do not double that.

But, if you want to write pure JSX without `styled-components` or something.

You can make the button mouseOver event fully controlled:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCloudUploadAlt } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export default function App() {
  const [over, setOver] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onMouseOver={() => setOver(true)}
        onMouseLeave={() => setOver(false)}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={faCloudUploadAlt}
          size="lg"
          style={over ? { color: "red" } : {}}
        />
        <span>Dataset Upload</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your rapid answer,  It works perfectly if I hover on the icon only but I need the same effect while hovering the button.  :)

Comment: Really? Use a `useState` react hook for just an `hover` event that can be achieved in one line using css? @tabrez I really don't recommend you to use this approach

Comment: @keikai  @tabrez Yeah sure that don't really need a `down-vote` but it's really painfull to see this type of react code as an answer :/

Answer (score -1):

```
//as component, take value as prop, if we pass color as prop, then its value will be immutable

<FaTimesCircle className="fa-icon" />


//css file

.fa-icon{color: blueviolet;}

.fa-icon:hover {color: rgb(255, 72, 72);}
```