# Problem: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, dom

Can someone help me, please?

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

[image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null]

I'm rendering this code, for example:

```
<div className="box">Test</div>
```

Comment: This would suggest that there is no `div.box`. Do you have a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: I'm rendering this code, for example: 


      <div className="box">Test</div>

Thank You!

Comment: Please upload some codes where this function is used

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `class` instead of `className`

Based on your update in the comment, you need to be using `class` and not `className`. `className` is a parameter passed to a react component, while `class` is the proper attribute for standard HTML elements.

Comment: I haven't heard of any differences between class and className like you said. Do you have a reference that I can take a look? I found this question and it doesn't align with your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989454/class-vs-classname-in-react-16