# Repeater with react

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am new to this and learning react at the moment. So i made a custom gutenberg block with 2 repeater fields. 1 is for a name and the second is for a number.

Technically it works. The fields are repeating etc. But the output i want to realize isn't  working or i dont get it.

So in the html i want that this block repeat it self but i dont know how.
If i repeat it once, it works like a charm. When i want to repeat it dubble or more, the output gets under the older output:

1 Field

```
<div class="skills__skills" >
  <div class="skills__skill">
   <p>{ skillnameFields }</p>
     <div class="container__bgcolor">
       <div class="skills html progress__skill" style={{width:{ percentFields } }}>
          <span>{ percentFields }</span>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

When i want 2 fields this happends:

```
<div class="skills__skills" >
      <div class="skills__skill">
       <p>{ skillnameFields }</p>
       <p>{ skillnameFields }</p>
         <div class="container__bgcolor">
           <div class="skills html progress__skill" style={{width:{ percentFields } }}>
              <span>{ percentFields }</span>
              <span>{ percentFields }</span>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

How can i make it work that this happends:

```
<div class="skills__skills" >
      <div class="skills__skill">
       <p>{ skillnameFields }</p>
         <div class="container__bgcolor">
           <div class="skills html progress__skill" style={{width:{ percentFields } }}>
              <span>{ percentFields }</span>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>

<div class="skills__skills" >
      <div class="skills__skill">
       <p>{ skillnameFields }</p>
         <div class="container__bgcolor">
           <div class="skills html progress__skill" style={{width:{ percentFields } }}>
              <span>{ percentFields }</span>
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
```

Here is mine full code:

I hope some on can help me :)

```
    /**
 * BLOCK: project-drie
 *
 * Registering a basic block with Gutenberg.
 * Simple block, renders and saves the same content without any interactivity.
 */

//  Import CSS.
import './editor.scss';
import './style.scss';


// import components
import { useBlockProps, RichText, InnerBlocks, MediaUpload, InspectorControls, } from '@wordpress/block-editor';


const { __ } = wp.i18n; // Import __() from wp.i18n
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks; // Import registerBlockType() from wp.blocks
const { Button, IconButton, PanelBody, TextareaControl, TextControl } = wp.components;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;


/**
 * Register: aa Gutenberg Block.
 *
 * Registers a new block provided a unique name and an object defining its
 * behavior. Once registered, the block is made editor as an option to any
 * editor interface where blocks are implemented.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/
 * @param  {string}   name     Block name.
 * @param  {Object}   settings Block settings.
 * @return {?WPBlock}          The block, if it has been successfully
 *                             registered; otherwise `undefined`.
 */


registerBlockType( 'cgb/block-project-drie-skillbar', {
    title: __( 'project-drie - Skill bar' ), // Block title.
    icon: 'shield', 
    category: 'project drie',
  supports: { 
        align: true,
    }, 
    keywords: [
        __( 'project-drie — CGB skillbar' ),
        __( 'skillbar' ),
        __( 'skill-bar' ),
    ],
  attributes: {
    title: {
      type: 'string',
      source: 'text',
      selector: 'figcaption',
    },
    subtitle: {
      type: 'string',
      source: 'text',
      selector: '.my-content',
    },
    mediaID: {
      type: 'number',
    },
    mediaURL: {
      type: 'string',
      source: 'attribute',
      selector: 'img',
      attribute: 'src',
    },
    skillname: {
            type: 'array',
            default: [],
        },
    percent: {
            type: 'array',
            default: [],
        },
  },

    /**
     * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the editor.
     * This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
     *
     * The "edit" property must be a valid function.
     *
     * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/block-edit-save/
     *
     * @param {Object} props Props.
     * @returns {Mixed} JSX Component.
     */


   edit: props => {
    const { attributes: {title, subtitle, mediaID, mediaURL }, className, setAttributes } = props;
    const onChangeTitle = title => { setAttributes ( { title } ) };
    const onChangeSubtitle = subtitle => { setAttributes ( { subtitle } ) };
    const onSelectImage = ( media ) => { setAttributes( { mediaURL: media.url, mediaID: media.id,} );};
    const handleAddSkillname = () => {
            const skillname = [ ...props.attributes.skillname ];
            skillname.push( {
                skill: '',
            } );
            props.setAttributes( { skillname } );
        };

    const handleAddPercent = () => {
            const percent = [ ...props.attributes.percent ];
            percent.push( {
                percentage: '',
            } );
            props.setAttributes( { percent } );
        };

    const handleRemoveSkillname = ( index ) => {
            const skillname = [ ...props.attributes.skillname ];
            skillname.splice( index, 1 );
            props.setAttributes( { skillname } );
        };

    const handleRemovePercent = ( index ) => {
            const percent = [ ...props.attributes.percent ];
            percent.splice( index, 1 );
            props.setAttributes( { percent } );
        };

    const handleSkillnameChange = ( skill, index ) => {
            const skillname = [ ...props.attributes.skillname ];
            skillname[ index ].skill = skill;
            props.setAttributes( { skillname } );
        };

    const handlePercentChange = ( percentage, index ) => {
            const percent = [ ...props.attributes.percent ];
            percent[ index ].percentage = percentage;
            props.setAttributes( { percent } );
        };

    let skillnameFields,
            skillnameDisplay;

    let percentFields,
            percentDisplay;

        if ( props.attributes.skillname.length ) {
            skillnameFields = props.attributes.skillname.map( ( skillname, index ) => {
                return <Fragment key={ index }>
                    <TextControl
                        className="skillbar__react__name"
                        placeholder="Add Skill Name. Example: HTML"
                        value={ props.attributes.skillname[ index ].skill }
                        onChange={ ( skill ) => handleSkillnameChange( skill, index ) }
                    />

                    <IconButton
                        className="skillbar__remove__react__name"
                        icon="no-alt"
                        label="Delete location"
                        onClick={ () => handleRemoveSkillname( index ) }
                    />
                </Fragment>;
            } );

        percentFields = props.attributes.percent.map( ( percent, index ) => {
                return <Fragment key={ index }>
                    <TextControl
                        className="skillbar__react__percent"
                        placeholder="Add Percent Skill. Example: 50%"
                        value={ props.attributes.percent[ index ].percentage }
                        onChange={ ( percentage ) => handlePercentChange( percentage, index ) }
                    />

                    <IconButton
                        className="skillbar__remove__react__percent"
                        icon="no-alt"
                        label="Delete location"
                        onClick={ () => handleRemovePercent( index ) }
                    />
                </Fragment>;
            } );

            skillnameDisplay = props.attributes.skillname.map( ( skillname, index ) => {
                return <p key={ index }>{ skillname.skill }</p>;
            } );

        percentDisplay = props.attributes.percent.map( ( percent, index ) => {
                return <p key={ index }>{ percent.percentage }</p>;
            } );
        }

        return [
      <div className={ className }>
            <InspectorControls key="1">
                <PanelBody title={ __( 'Skill Name' ) }>
                    { skillnameFields }
                    <Button
                        isDefault
                        onClick={ handleAddSkillname.bind( this ) }
                    >
                        { __( 'Add Name' ) }
                    </Button>
                </PanelBody>
          <PanelBody title={ __( 'Percent' ) }>
                    { percentFields }
                    <Button
                        isDefault
                        onClick={ handleAddPercent.bind( this ) }
                    >
                        { __( 'Add percent' ) }
                    </Button>
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
            <div key="2" className={ props.className }>
          <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-skillbar-repeater">
            <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-skillbar-repeater-title">
              <p> Press on Skill bar</p>
                    <h2>Skill Bar</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-skillbar-skillname">
              <h3>Skill Name</h3>{ skillnameDisplay }
            </div>
            <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-skillbar-percentage">
              <h3>percentage</h3>{ percentDisplay }
            </div>
          </div>
            </div>
        <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-skillbar-info">
          <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-skillbar-title">
            <h2>{ __('Title', 'cgb')}</h2>
              <RichText
                tagName="div"
                className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-skillbar-titles"
                placeholder={ __('Add your title here', 'cgb')}
                onChange={ onChangeTitle}
                value={ title }
              />
          </div>
          <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-skillbar-subtext">
          <h2>{ __('Sub-Text', 'cgb')}</h2>
            <RichText
              tagName="p"
              className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-skillbar-subtexts"
              value={ subtitle }
              onChange={ onChangeSubtitle }
              placeholder={ __('Add your sub-text here', 'cgb')}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-skillbar-bgimages">
          <h2>Right Side Image</h2>
          <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-skillbar-bgimage">
            <MediaUpload
              onSelect={ onSelectImage }
              allowedTypes="image"
              value={ mediaID }
              render={ ( { open } ) => (
                  <Button className={ mediaID ? 'image-button' : 'button button-large' } onClick={ open }>
                      { ! mediaID ? __( 'Upload Image', 'gutenberg-examples' ) : <img src={ mediaURL } alt={ __( 'Upload Recipe Image', 'gutenberg-examples' ) } /> }
                  </Button>
              ) }
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        ];

    },

    /**
     * The save function defines the way in which the different attributes should be combined
     * into the final markup, which is then serialized by Gutenberg into post_content.
     *
     * The "save" property must be specified and must be a valid function.
     *
     * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/block-edit-save/
     *
     * @param {Object} props Props.
     * @returns {Mixed} JSX Frontend HTML.
     */
    save: ( props ) => {
    const {attributes: { title } } = props;
    const {attributes: { subtitle } } = props;
    const {attributes: { mediaURL} } = props;
    const skillnameFields = props.attributes.skillname.map( ( skillname, index ) => {
            return <p key={ index }>{ skillname.skill }</p>;
        } );
    const percentFields = props.attributes.percent.map( ( percent, index ) => {
            return <p key={ index }>{ percent.percentage }</p>;
        } );

    return (
      <section class="skills_bar">
        <div class="container skills__container">
          <div class="row skills__row">
            <div class="skills__content">
              <div class="skills__info col-md-6">
                <div class="skills__text">
                  <div class="skills__title">
                    <h2>{ title } </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="skills__subtext">
                    <p>{ subtitle }</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="skills__skills" >
                  <div class="skills__skill">
                    <p>{ skillnameFields }</p>
                    <div class="container__bgcolor">
                      <div class="skills html progress__skill" style={{width:{ percentFields } }}>
                        <span>{ percentFields }</span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="skills__images col-md-6">
                <div class="skills__image">
                  <img src={ mediaURL}/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
    },
 } );
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your specific data model, but one solution would be to combine your `skillname` and `percent` attributes into a single `skills` attribute. That would be an `array` of `object`s. Then for your output you simply loop over the `skills` array and output the object pieces. In your edit function, when you add a new skill, just push the `object` into the `skills` array (e.g. `setAttributes({skills: [...skills, {name: 'Skill name', percent: 50}]})`).

```js
attributes: {
  skills: {
    type: 'array',
    default: [],
  },
}
```

```js
save: ({attributes}) => {
  return skills.map((skill) => (
    <div className="skills__skills" key={ skill.name }>
      <div className="skills__skill">
        <p>{ skill.name }</p>
        <div className="container__bgcolor">
          <div className="skills html progress__skill">
            <span>{ skill.percent }</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Also, you'll want to use `className` instead of `class` or React will give you an error since `class` is a reserved word in JS. [See this issue for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46989454/class-vs-classname-in-react-16).

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer!! I got it worked as i wanted :)